# mvn spring-boot:run doesn't start spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

**ANSWER: I changed the version tag from 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT to 1.0.2.RELEASE and it worked, see answer below.**

I am following this [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-documentation) and have created the Example.java as instructed. When I run `mvn spring-boot:run` spring doesn't start it just says BUILD SUCCESS. It's my understanding that Spring should start and Tomcat serving up the page.

```
E:\workspace\SpringBoot>mvn spring-boot:run
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building myproject 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:run (default-cli) @ myproject >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory E:\workspace\SpringBoot\src\main\resources
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory E:\workspace\SpringBoot\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory E:\workspace\SpringBoot\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ myproject ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:run (default-cli) @ myproject <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:run (default-cli) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.108 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-05-01T14:54:26-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/232M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here are some details:

```
E:\workspace\SpringBoot>java -version
java version "1.7.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode)

E:\workspace\SpringBoot>mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-14T12:37:52-05:00)
Maven home: E:\apps\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin\..
Java version: 1.7.0_21, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Example.java located at E:\workspace\SpringBoot\src\main\java:

```
import org.springframework.boot.*;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Example {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String home() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Example.class, args);
    }

}
```

pom.xml located at E:\workspace\SpringBoot:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>   

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- (you don't need this if you are using a .RELEASE version) -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Comment: Try it with spring-boot 1.0.2.RELEASE. The "run" mojo changed in 1.1.0 snapshots and you might have hit a Windows-specific problem with it (looks like maybe the app is running but you aren't seeing the console output).

Comment: Awesome this worked! Spring now started and the page is now being served!

Comment: so... I just started spring boot but what URL do I go to to check it out? I went to localhost:8080 and I don't see anything

Comment: @mmcrae By default it should be localhost:8080, can you provide your setup and output? Also are you using spring-mvc and have a proper RequestMapping setup for "/"?

Comment: Aha, right there's no Controllers actually generated. There's no web.xml or any spring-servlet.xml files auto-generated. I thought that Spring boot would do some of that. It generated Application.java which has a main method which calls `SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);` (so it's running itself er... something). Where would I put some Controller classes in this case? I'm caught off guard because I know the application's entry point is `SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);` but idk how to fit in the actual web stuff i.e. Controller classes

Comment: @mmcrae, you need to define your controllers with annotations or in xml. Follow this guide http://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/ or this guide http://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

Comment: thank you! -- I found the second link much more useful. It seems to me the first link is somewhat out dated -- using Ant as the build tool rather than Maven or Gradle, and some of the environment config / directory structure seems different.

Comment: Till day same error with boot 1.5.8.RELEASE, 
INFO: Started WebAppInitializer in 0.984 seconds (JVM running for 6.838)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.563 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-01T19:23:55+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/250M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try it with spring-boot 1.0.2.RELEASE. The "run" mojo changed in 1.1.0 snapshots and you might have hit a Windows-specific problem with it (looks like maybe the app is running but you aren't seeing the console output).

Update: that bug is now fixed, so it should work on 1.1.0 as well.

Answer (score 10):

Your pom is missing the Spring Boot Maven Plugin:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Where do I put this? I put it into my pom.xml but got the same result:

Comment: You put it in your pom at the same level as repositories/pluginRepositories/etc.  Can you post your updated Pom?

Comment: I just updated my pom.xml in the original post above.

Comment: I just created a new application with your updated pom and Example class you have above and it runs fine with `$ mvn spring-boot:run`

Comment: @MichaelMinella can you share how to pass jar file with "mvn spring-boot:run" command to so that it will load and scan by spring

Answer (score 6):

I changed the version tag from 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT to 1.0.2.RELEASE and it worked:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>   

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- (you don't need this if you are using a .RELEASE version) -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Spring now started:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::  (v1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT)
```

Answer (score 2):

I Went for the latest version and **selected** **mvc in dependencies** from starter generater page (after being fed up with this). All worked like breeze.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with similar problem while refactoring multiple pom.xml at the maven multi-project. Problem began when while 'mvn clean install' Spring didn't start, but he did it before.
This problem disappeared when I moved properties-section of maven-surefire-plugin from root-module to the domain-module. Then I discovered that this dependency was redundant and I removed her. This fix looks to be strange but it helped me.